# Web page fonts and accessability

Tags: css, fonts, accessibility, typography

Is there a way to detect if the browser is using its default font and only apply a font if it is? I want to use Helvetica for readability but don't want to override users' font choices.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a good way of detecting default fonts, but there are a few JavaScript methods you could use to look for styles on an element :

**Computed Styles** - The `getComputedStyle` method can be used to access which styles have been applied to an element:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("your-selector")).fontFamily;
```

**Styles in the Document Head** - You can check for [style elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) in the document with:

```
document.querySelectorAll("style")
```

**Inline Styles** - You can get [inline styles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/style) of individual elements for the font-family property with:

```
document.querySelector("your-selector").style.fontFamily
```

**External Stylesheets** - [External stylesheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) loaded through a `<link>` element can be detected with:

```
document.querySelectorAll("link[rel=stylesheet]")
```

Comment: Okay thank a lot for the info :)